# How to get fixed height of any screen in react JS without keyboard height (for web)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, height, screen, fixed

window.innerHeight or window.outerHeight are not working. When keyboard is on its take height from the top of keyboard in mobile.

I want to get the fixed height of screen which is not change when keyboard is on in mobile.

Comment: @YosiLeibman I think you misread, the OP spoke of **keyboard**, not of **keyword**.